# How to manage Animation states in react native with Redux?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have an animation like code below:

```
 Animated.spring(this.state.scale, {
            toValue: this.props.scaleTo,
            friction: 1,
        }).start();
```

And for my thought with Redux, I should call code below to change the state  rather than the way change the state above:

```
            this.store.dispatch(createScaleChangeAction(this.props.scaleFrom));
```

But the problem is I really don't know **How and  Where** to do it?

Comment: I think you are new with redux, first welcome. It's not good idea to use *this.store.dispatch*. It's better to see some react native redux examples. https://github.com/alinz/example-react-native-redux is a good example for starting redux in react-native.

Comment: I know the "react-redux", but my point is how to manage the states of animation (not the normal state, the state will be changed by Animated automatically)? I know it's easy to manage it using local state.but how to manage it using redux even though I have already split the component into container and presentation components.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#working-with-animations), `start()` takes a callback function. On completion, you can dispatch an action to your reducer by passing the your dispatch function into `start()`.